# Any benefit putting controller/model//service/persistence into different module in maven?

Tags: java, maven, module, architecture, structure

I saw a couple of Java projects were organized in this way by Maven:

```
<modules>
    <module>XX-services-controller</module>
    <module>XX-services-persistence</module>
    <module>XX-services-service</module>
    <module>XX-services-model</module>
    <module>XX-services-common</module>
</modules>
```

I can understand the need for XX-services-common but I can't see any benefit of separating controller/view/service into different modules. Controller/View/Service is just layer, they won't be deployed independently, why there is such practice?

Or actually this is bad practice that we should avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bad practice at all. When you are separating into different modules like this these modules could be used by multiple other module which result in less code repetition.

For example, `XX-services-persistence` this module can be used for persisting date to DB. So when any other module wants to persist data to DB this module can be used. If this module is not separated then other modules will have to implement methods to persist data which will result in code duplication.

Comment: i think it make sense if each module was build into a jar/war file that can be imported/deployed. If a module was not set to build into a jar/war, even the persistence layer was not in a separate module, other code/module can still just call persistence layer code to do persist data, right? I don't see why there is code duplication.